# how to add a new item to ebay using ebay API

Tags: php, ebay-api

i want to add an item to ebay using ebay API and PHP i read their website for hours and i'm lost. i created a developer account. but what should i do after that? i read about "Add item" call http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/AddItem.html but i have no idea on how to use that?

Please help !!

Comment: Uh... did you try the link near the top that reads "Tutorials"?

Answer (score 2):

Please check this code here

https://github.com/rishiv3/ebayAddItem

I have made for adding new items on ebay also you can upload max 12 images with that and if needed you can store values on your database as well.

Just grab the keys from registering here

http://developer.ebay.com

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to taking a look at the eBay tutorial, I've thrown a [wrapper around the eBay Accelerator toolkit](https://github.com/iloveitaly/ebay-php/blob/master/eBayCommon.php) that might be useful for some sample / example code.